# How to read a file from certain path

Tags: ios, swift, file

I'm trying to read and write a file from a path (ex: "/Desktop/folder"). If this can't be done, then from Documents (ex: "/Documents/folder"). I saw and tried several examples, but the problem is that the file is located in a location such:

> file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AE6A47DE-D6D0-49AE-B39F-25C7A2335DC8/data/Containers/Data/Application/09F890C1-081F-46E7-88BC-F8453BAFC1CB/Documents/Test.txt"
>   0x00006000000af780

Even if i have the "Test.txt" in Documents and even in project.

Here's the code which reads and writes a file at the above location:

```
 let file = "Test.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

    let text = "some text" //just a text

    var text2 = ""

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

        //writing
        do {
            try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */print(error)}

        //reading
        do {
             text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */ print(error)}
    }
```

Is it possible to read and write file from path i need (ex: "Documents/Folder")?

Comment: You can only read/write to certain "sandboxed" directories like `Documents` and `Caches` (or subdirectories inside those.) Yes, you should be able to read/write to `Documents/Folder`. Edit your question to show your code that does that, rather than the code above, that just tries to write to a file in `Documents`.

Comment: I don't have the code to read from "Documents/Folder", that's what i need.

Comment: https://github.com/dreymonde/AppFolder

Comment: That's just too much to integrate in my project. Isn't there a short version like the code i posted to read the file from "Documents/Folder"?

Comment: Yes there is. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, like you're doing now, take the documents dir, and append the path you need:

```
let file = "Test.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

guard let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, 
  in: .userDomainMask).first { else return }

let subDir = dir.appendingPathComponent("Folder", isDirectory: true)
let fileURL = subDir.appendingPathComponent(file)
```

Note that trying to write to that file URL will fail if the sub-folder "Folder" doesn't already exist. You'd have to use one of the file manager createDirectory calls to create the "Folder" directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The path is still: "file:///Users/Name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AE6A47DE-D6D0-49AE-B39F-25C7A2335DC8/data/Containers/Data/Application/E3FE833B-D62B-48D7-B82C-EC8450C0FCDC/Documents/Folder/Test.txt" 0x00006040000b23c0 even with your change

Comment: The actual path is going to be to a folder in the app's sandboxed documents directory. That's what all that stuff at the beginning of the path is."

Comment: There **is no** shared documents directory on iOS. Each app has it's own sandbox that includes an app-specific documents directory.

Comment: but my folder i need isn't there. As i saw, it creates a new folder at the path above. However i find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

```
  let file = "Test.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it
            let text = "some text" //just a text
            var text2 = ""

            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/name/Documents/Folder/Test.txt")
                //writing
                do {
                    try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
                }
                catch {/* error handling here */print(error)}
                //reading
                do {
                    text2 = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
                    var s = ""
                }
                catch {/* error handling here */ print(error)}
            }
```

Comment: That code will not work on an actual (non jailbroken) device. iOS apps do not have access to `/Users/username/Documents`, only to their sandboxed Documents directory.

Comment: Make sure you test your code on an actual device (**where it will fail**). Bear in mind that the simulator runs on Mac OS, which has a very different file system. You can do things on the sim that are not allowed on a device.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to mention. I don't need this for an actual mobile app. I need for a homework in which i don't apply any mobile specific things, just the language.

Comment: Ok, but understand that what you are doing is wrong and won't work. The fact that it DOES work on the simulator is a bug.

Comment: I don't even use the simulator. I just write in file. I use this as a desktop app and i didn't wanted to write the app in java.

Comment: The path that you listed in your question makes it clear that you ARE using the simulator.

Comment: Without my will. I didn't wanted that path.

Comment: Ok. You built an iOS app. If you run an iOS app without a device, it's on the simulator. If you build an iOS app, it runs directly on the Mac. You might want to build a Mac OS command line tool.